# Linux Script to check if process is running and restart if not

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cron, pid

I am having this script which looks for the process **filebeat** and restarts it if is not running. Cron runs this script every 5 minutes. Most of the time this works fine except sometime it creates multiple filebeat process. Can someone please point out what is the issue in my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
service=filebeat
servicex=/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat
pid=`pgrep -x "filebeat"`
if [ $pid > /dev/null ]
then
echo "$(date) $service is running!!!"
else
echo "$(date) starting $service"
cd /home/hpov/beats/filebeat
./filebeat -c filebeat.yml &
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
pidof  script.x86 >/dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
        echo "Restarting script:     $(date)" >> /var/log/script.txt
        /etc/script/script.x86 &
fi
```

Super easy :D